# Function such that $\left(\int_{\mathbb R}u\right)^2=\int_{\mathbb R}u^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Are there function $u$ s.t.
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb R}u\right)^2=\int_{\mathbb R}u^2 \ \ ?$$

Or at least $$\left(\int_a^b u\right)^2=\int_a^b u^2 \ \ ?$$

I can see for the second one that for $u$ constant it works, but are there un constant function ?

Comment: If $a<0<1<b$ then the characteristic function of $[0,1]$ works.

Comment: $u= e^{-4|x|}$ works in the first case.

Comment: $u = e^{-2\pi x^2}$ as well.

Answer (score 4):

Jensen's inequality says that

$$\left ( \int_a^b f(x) dx \right )^2 \leq (b-a) \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx$$

and there is equality if and only if $f$ is almost everywhere constant. So your equality will be possible for non-constant functions as soon as $b-a>1$. In that case there will be many examples. For instance, consider functions that take on two values, then you're looking at essentially the equation

$$(p_1 y_1 + p_2 y_2)^2 = (p_1 y_1^2 + p_2 y_2^2) \\
p_1 \geq 0,p_2 \geq 0,p_1+p_2=b-a$$

where $p_1$ is the measure of $\{ x : f(x)=y_1 \}$ and analogous for $p_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "if and only if $f$ is almost everywhere constant"? You have not expressed the (relative) bounds to make this a completely definitive mathematical statement, but my simple example of $\sqrt{u}$ can hardly be said to be almost constant across the interval of integration. I'm confused.

Comment: Arrh sorry Its the $(b-a)$ factor that explains it, $\left(\int_0^{9/8}\sqrt{u}\; du\right)^2 < \frac{9}{8} \int_0^{9/8}(\sqrt{u})^2\; du$

Comment: @JamesArathoon Really the right inequality is $\left ( \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx \right )^2 \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx$. What I wrote here is what you get after you multiply through by $(b-a)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

One simple non-exponential example of the second case is

$$\left(\int_0^{9/8}\sqrt{u}\; du\right)^2=\int_0^{9/8}(\sqrt{u})^2\; du$$

Graph of $u$ (in blue) and $\sqrt{u}$ over  the interval $0$ to $\frac98$

[image: u and sqrt u compared]